# Understanding the word 'generic'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know my question may be somewhat basic but stick with me for a second. I've looked online at various websites explaining what this word is, but I just can't understand it.

The reason I need to clear this word is for a programming language. I'm somewhat an unintelligent person that finds it hard to understand things.

Can anyone put this in a simple way, that even an idiot would understand?

I've looked on various websites such as Urban Dictionary, [google definitions](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=what%20does%20generic%20mean) and the [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/generic).

Comment: Kindly post a couple of your online findings, definitions and a sample sentence per per forum rules>

Comment: I have updated my question with some links.

Comment: [Generic bread](https://www.alternet.org/sites/default/files/story_images/bread.png)

Comment: [Generic aspirin](http://www.livingwithatrialfibrillation.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/aspirin-for-atrial-fibrillation.jpg)

Comment: In a programming context, *generic* means a piece of code that’s not tied to *any specific type of value*. You can write a single function, that, for example, counts how many `A`s are in list `B`, and so long as the type of `A` is the same as the type of `B`, it *does not matter what that type is*. The code would be identical for counting the number of `0`s in a list of numbers, the number of `Q`s in a list of letters, the number of `Kumquats` in a list of `Fruits`, and so on. Generics permit this with he generality of super abstract impl (say of `Object`s) but the type safety of specific impl

Comment: In a programming context "generic" means what the language spec says it means.  There's a wide range of meanings.

Comment: Definitions are useless if they aren't understood in context. What we need are **examples** of use of the word in actual sentences emitted by actual English speakers in the context you're interested in. No data means no explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why are you looking in dictionaries for the meaning of a programming term? You should be using resources specific to the programming language that you are using, like [this Stack Overflow question for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77632/6083675).